# Как использовать переменную в xpath?

Tags: xml, plsql, xpath

Ситуация следующая, нужно извлечь значение следующим запросом:

```
select 
    EXTRACTVALUE(
        xmltype(core_gzip.gunzip_to_clob(p_blob => ptn.changed_variable)), 
        '/`*`:TraceVariables/`*`:**Variable[@Id=v_variable_id_device]**'||
        '/`*`:Process1/`*`:Requests/`*`:Process1_Request/`*`:DeviceId'
    )   
into v_device_id   
from process_trace pt;
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как присвоить атрибуту `Id` значение переменной.

Тип данных переменной пробовал задать `number` и `varchar`, что не помогло. Так что, видимо не в этом дело.
При этом, если я задаю, к примеру, `@Id=1234`, то всё работает прекрасно.
А в моём случае по итогу в переменную заносится просто пустое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
@Id=' || v_variable_id_device || '
```